# One to one bi direction mapping is not working

Tags: spring

My code contains two entities, that have relation with each other.

Student Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_detail_id")
    private StudentDetail studentDetail;

    public Student() {}

    //getters setters
```

StudentDetail Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_detail")
public class StudentDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "college")
    private String college;

    @Column(name = "no_of_problems_solved")
    private int noOfProblemsSolved;

    public StudentDetail() {}
    @Column(name = "college")
    private String college;

    @Column(name = "no_of_problems_solved")
    private int noOfProblemsSolved;

    public StudentDetail() {}
```

Why is the one to one bi direction mapping not working?

Comment: *is not working* means?

Answer (score 0):

In Student_Detail you have to specify @OntToOne Annotation also.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_detail")
public class StudentDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "college")
    private String college;

    @Column(name = "no_of_problems_solved")
    private int noOfProblemsSolved;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "studentDetail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Student student;
    //Getters setters
}
```

This should work for you.